# Xcode how to change tab in code

Tags: ios, xcode, indexing, tabbar

I'm trying to change the tab bar index on a click:

I'm using the code in the webViewDidStartLoad:

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *) webView {

    NSRange catalog = [WebView.request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString: @"catalog"];    
    if(catalog.location != NSNotFound)    {
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex: 1];   
    }
}
```

But when I do this, I can't change the index of the tab bar later on, it keeps stuck on 1.
And the view that's on the index 1 doesn't load...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The method you use is correct so there must be an issue elsewhere in the code.

Comment: When I start the app I can navigate through all the tabs, but after I use this code it doesn't work...

Comment: post some code around your line, where do you call it?

Comment: I've edited my post, I'm using the code in the webViewDidStartLoad. If it is a certain link it should be displayed on another tab..

Comment: Need some more background on what you are trying to do - what is the connection between the UIWebView and the tab bar? How is the tab bar, the views, and the uiwebview all plumbed together?